# value of binding operator expression in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have some doubt about the outcome of a binding operator expression in perl. I mean expression like

```
string =~ /pattern/
```

I have done some simple test

```
$ss="a1b2c3";
say $ss=~/a/;   # 1
say $ss=~/[a-z]/g;  # abc
@aa=$ss=~/[a-z]/g;say @aa;  # abc
$aa=@aa;say $aa;    # 3
$aa=$ss=~/[a-z]/g;say $aa;  # 1
```

note the comment part above is the running result.

So here comes the question, what on earth is returned by `$ss=~/[a-z]/g`, it seems that it returned an array according to code line 3,4,5. But what about the last line, why it gives 1 instead of 3 which is the length of array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return of the match operator depends on the context: in list context it returns all captured matches, in scalar context the true/false. The `say` imposes list context, but in the first example nothing is captured in the regex so you only get "success."

Next, the behavior of `/g` modifier also differs across contexts. In list context, with it the string keeps being scanned with the given pattern until all matches are found, and a list with them is returned.  These are your second and third examples.

But in scalar context its behavior is a bit specific: with it the search will continue from the position of the last match, the next time round. One typical use is in the loop condition

```
while (/(\w+)/g) { ... }
```

This is a bit of a tokenizer: after the body of the loop runs the next word is found, etc.

Then the last example doesn't really make sense; you are getting the "normal" scalar-context matching success/fail, and `/g` doesn't do anything -- until you match on `$ss` the next time

```
perl -wE'
    $s=shift||q(abc); 
    for (1..2) { $m = $s=~/(.)/g; say "$m: $1"; }
'
```

prints lines `1:a` and then `1:b`.

Outside of iterative structures (like `while` condition) the `/g` in scalar context is usually an error, pointless at best or a quiet bug.

See "*Global matching*" under ["Using regular expressions" in perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl) for `/g`.
See [regex operators in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) in general, and about `/g` as well. A useful tool to explore `/g` workings is [pos](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation. I really had a very wrong view of `/g` modifier before. Thanks for clarifying `/g` and those context things.

Comment: @user15964  Most welcome :).  The `/g` is indeed tricky, by context-dependent behavior. (If you want to play and see what it does a useful tool is [pos](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos.html).)  In general, context is one of the crucial concepts in Perl, and practically unavoidable.